Difference between two IAudioClient::Initialize return values
I'm having trouble understanding the documentation for the IAudioClient::Initialize() function.
It's about the different return values E_INVALIDARG and AUDCLNT_E_UNSUPPORTED_FORMAT.
The E_INVALIDARG description says:

Parameter pFormat points to an invalid format description.

However, in the description for AUDCLNT_E_UNSUPPORTED_FORMAT:

The audio engine (shared mode) or audio endpoint device (exclusive mode) does not support the specified format.

What does it mean in E_INVALIDARG that the description format is "invalid"? I guess it's not that it doesn't fit the device, since that's already handled by AUDCLNT_E_UNSUPPORTED_FORMAT?
And, it's also not that it is pFormat == NULL, since that's already handled by E_POINTER.
So, what specific cases is pFormat incorrectness covered by E_INVALIDARG?

E_INVALIDARG passed a parameter that is not in the required range for the function.  AUDCLNT_E_UNSUPPORTED_FORMAT passed a valid parameter for the function but the selected device does not support it.

@RichardCritten Do you know what it means that the WAVEFORMATEX argument is out of required range?

@MieszkoPasierbek Could be anything but most likely it just rejects bogus values. Like sampleRate of 0 Hz, or channel count of -3, or 999-bit audio. Whereas AUDCLNT_E_UNSUPPORTED_FORMAT means "format is sane, but not supported". For example your hardware cannot do stereo 192000Hz 32-bit float.

It also explains more about AUDCLNT_E_UNSUPPORTED_FORMAT. Before calling Initialize to set up a shared-mode or exclusive-mode connection, the client can call the IAudioClient::IsFormatSupported method to discover whether the audio engine or audio endpoint device supports a particular format in that mode.
